# How to Convert []uint8 to string

Tags: go

I am observing the log of a program in the Go, and in the output I see this:

```
[]uint8=[18 32 96 38 15 212 226 233 58 14 183 212 80 4 175 97 28 235 76 154 244 210 200 18 131 241 31 86 179 109 228 190 78 72])
```

Now I would like to be able to convert this to a form where I can see what it means. This should be string content represented as `[]uint8`.

But when I call the `string` method on that value as suggested in this link [here](https://yourbasic.org/golang/convert-string-to-byte-slice/) I get a gibberish output.

[Go Playground link here](https://play.golang.org/p/VoMNGcbqWoa)

What could I be doing wrong and how to go about this conversion?

Comment: first element 18 (0x12) is not printable character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conversion `s := string(stuff)` is fine, but usually you'd expect `stuff` to contain actual printable character sequences. In your case, it doesn't (mostly).

Make sure to read [Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings) in detail.

---

Modifying your example to print byte values that have ASCII letter mappings:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    stuff := []byte{97, 98, 99, 100}
    s := string(stuff)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

[Prints "abcd"](https://play.golang.org/p/jozgt09vtSA).

Answer (score 1):

Actually your code is ok which you mention in GO Playground & there is nothing wrong.

And `[]byte{18, 32, 112, 236, 92, 145, 161, 6, 131, 219, 133, 202, 254, 245, 176, 35, 42, 161, 94, 140, 190, 7, 216, 132, 6, 225, 132, 162, 24, 48, 197, 33, 11, 111}`  here some element are not able to print the character. So I think you should get idea of ASCII Table. Then you will never confused about output.

visit on this https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html to get the idea of ASCII Table